# Paul's Online notes example seems to be wrong? Variations of parameters diff equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[Paul's Online Note Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL8op.png)

As far as I know, the complementary solution only consists of cos and sin when the roots are complex. From what I see, the roots for this equation are r=0 or r=-9. Not complex. Am I missing something?

Comment: The roots of $2 r^2 + 18$ are $\pm 3 i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of the equation $a^{2}+9=0$ are $\pm 3i$. (You are probably looking at $a^{2}+9a=0$).

Comment: Yep thats it.. The good ol mistake of treating y as y'. thank you